# converting numeric,string to datetime in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a datetime coming in 4 different columns ( year,month,date,time) and values are (2001,01,01,1600Z)

How do I convert to datetime in python?

Answer (score 0):

Using `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
dList = [(2001,01,01,'1600Z'), (2001,01,01,'1700Z')]
for i in dList:
    print( datetime.datetime(year=i[0], month=i[1], day=i[2], hour=int(i[3][:-3])) )
```

**Output:**

```
2001-01-01 16:00:00
2001-01-01 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `datetime.strptime` function (the [formatting rules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) are described in the documentation):

```
from datetime import datetime

values = (
('2001','01','01','1600Z'),
('2002','02','03','1500Z'),
('2003','02','03','1400Z'),
)

for v in values:
    d = datetime.strptime('-'.join(v), '%Y-%m-%d-%H%MZ')
    print(d)
```

Prints:

```
2001-01-01 16:00:00
2002-02-03 15:00:00
2003-02-03 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> tp=(2001,01,01,'1600Z')
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(tp[0],tp[1],tp[2],int(tp[3][:-3]),int(tp[3][2:][:-1]))
>>> print dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import datetime

val=(2001,01,01,"1600Z")
d=datetime.strptime("%s %s %s %s" %(val[0],val[1],val[2],val[3]), "%Y %m %d %H%MZ")

print d.isoformat()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dateutil` package to parse datetime. You can install `dateutil` package by doing `pip install python-dateutil`

```
from dateutil import parser
date = parse('-'.join(('2001','01','01','1600Z')))
print (date)
# 2001-01-01 16:00:00+00:00
```